# Problem in installing and configuring latest python 3.8 on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I've been trying to install Python 3.8 on MacOS via homebrew but I ended up with many versions of Python.

```
$ which python3
$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
$ ls
$ 3.6   3.8
```

How do I fix it so that I get 3.8 to be the default python version?

Comment: on Linux I have commands `python3`, `python3.6`, `python3.7`, `python3.8` and I don't have to set default version because I can use `python3.8`. Besides system uses Python to run some elements. If I would change default version then system would have problem to run.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, currently we are still working on moving to Python 3.8 (too many Homebrew formula dependencies and Jenkins CI often runs out of the disk space).

Here is mega issue tracker: [Github python 3.8 migration issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/47274).

For the time being, I would recommend to use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), which I am using it to manage multiple python versions myself for development as well.

Here is what you need to do:

- `brew install pyenv`
- `pyenv init`
- `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` # be sure `echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' > ~/.bash_profile` for the future shell sessions.
- `pyenv install 3.8.0`
- `pyenv global 3.8.0`

And then you are good to go.

Comment: For macOS Catalina version 10.15.+, you can append `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` to `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile`. Since bash is not the default shell anymore.